# Cannot resolve symbol 'java'

Tags: java, cucumber

In the inteliji, I have tried to produce the steps out of a gherkin file.

```
import cucumber.api.PendingException;

public class LoginStep {
    @cucumber.api.java.en.Then("^I should see userform page$")
    public void iShouldSeeUserformPage() throws Throwable {

        throw new PendingException();
    }
}
```

In the line `@cucumber.api.java.en.Then` it complains with

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'java'
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

How can i resolve it?

Comment: Are you using `maven`? Have you added `cucumber-java` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Your should add `cucumber-java` dependency.

```
<dependencies>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
   <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```